# Can I style these divs so that they are inline with a break at the end

Tags: css, html

I want the display to be something like this.

```
Div1 Div2
Div3 Div4
```

The html is like this:

```
<div class="class1">Div1</div> <div class="class2">Div2</div>
<div class="class1">Div3</div> <div class="class2">Div4</div>
```

Stylesheet is like this:

```
.class1
{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:9pt;
    display:inline-block;
}

.class2
{
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:9pt;
    display:inline;   
}
```

Using pure CSS, I'd like to be able to arrange the layout to be like I mentioned above.

Is it possible to do this with CSS without wrapping a class1 and a class2 inside a container div?

Comment: With these conditions: no clearing allowed, unspecified width, and there will most likely be enough room for all 4 elements to appear on the same line?  If you were to force the elements to be 50% wide (including margin/padding/border), then yes.  Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/pxpvw/1

```
.class1 {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

.class2 {
    float: left;  
}
```

Comment: This works on an empty page, but doesn't work properly if you already have a stack of items on the left side that are already float left.

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` in `.class1`

```
.class1
{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:9pt;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

You will get result as you want.

Comment: This won't work if you already have items that are left of these divs that are already float:left

Answer (score 0):

Float:left for all of them and than adding a margin-right value so that .class3 element goes under.